# Jmeter: Getting NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/LogTarget

Tags: java, jmeter

I have tried to invoke my existing jmx file through java code. I have added the external jars to the project of the type: ApacheJmeter_core, commons-logging,jorphan and log4j.

Yet, i get the the following error when i run my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log/LogTarget
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.<clinit>(StandardJMeterEngine.java:56)
    at com.InvokeJmeterScript.runFirstJmeterScript.main(runFirstJmeterScript.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log.LogTarget
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

**Please tell me the solution for this problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particular this error stands for missing [logkit-2.0.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/logkit/logkit/2.0)

In general you need all the jars from /lib and /lib/ext folders plus any custom jars if they are used in script in your project's classpath in order to be able to run a JMeter test.

More on topic in [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide.